# geddy command breaks after creating geddy app

Tags: node.js, geddy

I'm following the geddy [tutorial](http://geddyjs.org/tutorial.html).

I install geddy & jake using npm, create the app, cd into the folder that is created, and run the geddy command. But I get an error when running the geddy command, here's my full output:

```
martin@crunchbang:~/code$ npm install geddy jake -g
/usr/local/bin/jake -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jake/bin/cli.js
/usr/local/bin/geddy -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/geddy/bin/cli.js
jake@0.2.33 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jake 
geddy@0.4.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/geddy 
martin@crunchbang:~/code$ geddy app geddy_todo
Created app geddy_todo.
martin@crunchbang:~/code$ cd geddy_todo/
martin@crunchbang:~/code/geddy_todo$ geddy

node.js:201
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'addListener'
at [object Object].<anonymous>           (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/geddy/lib/cluster/master.js:25:11)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/geddy/bin/cli.js:109:9
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/geddy/bin/cli.js:181:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
at Array.0 (module.js:470:10)
at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
martin@crunchbang:~/code/geddy_todo$
```

After running those commands the geddy command seems to be broken wherever I run it I get the following:

```
martin@crunchbang:~$ geddy

node.js:201
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'addListener'
at [object Object].<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/geddy/lib/cluster/master.js:25:11)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/geddy/bin/cli.js:109:9
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/geddy/bin/cli.js:181:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
at Array.0 (module.js:470:10)
at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

When I run:

```
npm rm geddy jake
```

I get

```
martin@crunchbang:~$ sudo npm rm geddy jake
npm WARN Not installed in /home/martin/node_modules geddy
npm WARN Not installed in /home/martin/node_modules jake
```

I'm unsure what to try next to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you don't have the latest version of node and npm installed. I can't be positive here, but try uninstalling node and npm and reinstalling the latest versions from http://nodejs.org.

You'll want to make sure you install Geddy and Jake as global packages.

```
npm install -g geddy jake
```